# Error [react-native-gesture-handler] react-native-gesture-handler module was not found

Tags: react-native

I get this error and I don't know why, although my app was running normally.

> ERROR  [react-native-gesture-handler] react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked properly (cd ios && pod install && cd ..).
>
> For installation instructions, please refer to https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation
> LOG  Running "aradismobile" with {"rootTag":41}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command to install it should be Work

if you are use yard then

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
```

or you are using npm

```
npm i react-native-gesture-handler
```

after that you need to `pod install`

```
cd ios && pod install
```